# \cite command prints both 'et al' and all the authors names

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

I am using the following citation

```
@article{valuation-basket-credit,
title={Valuation of basket credit derivatives in the credit migrations     environment},
author={Bielecki, T.R.  and Cr{\'e}pey, S.  and Jeanblanc, M. and Rutkowski, M.},
journal={Handbooks in Operations Research and Management Science},
volume={15},
pages={471--507},
year={2007},
publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

which I reference inside the document using the command \cite{}. My bibliography style is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
....
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{file}
```

Yet, the result I get is the following

[image]

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a compilable tex code, not only a code snippet.  For example which document class do you use, which packages with which options which change or defines the layout of your bibliography ...

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but still relevant: Using the entry type `@article` is not correct for the entry at hand. You should be using the type `@incollection`, with `editor = "John R. Birge and Vadim Linetsky",`, `booktitle="Financial Engineering",`, `chapter=11,`, and `series = "Handbooks in Operations Research and Management Science",`. Also, insert a space between the initials of the first author.

Comment: Have you loaded the `natbib` package?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the documentclass I use is book. In addition, I can change the reference to incollection, once I fix the citation style error.

Comment: Thank you Mico. It required the natbib package. Once I used it it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the `natbib` package when using the bibliography style `elsarticle-num-names`.

Separately, you shouldn't employ the `@article` entry type for this entry as it isn't published in a journal. Instead, use the `@incollection` entry type:

```
@incollection{bielecki-etal:2007,
author    = "Tomasz R. Bielecki and St{\'e}phane Cr{\'e}pey and Monique Jeanblanc and Marek Rutkowski",
title     = "Valuation of Basket Credit Derivatives in the Credit Migrations Environment",
chapter   = 11,
editor    = "John R. Birge and Vadim Linetsky",
booktitle = "Financial Engineering",
publisher = "Elsevier",
year      = 2007,
volume    = 15,
pages     = 471--507,
series    = "Handbooks in Operations Research and Management Science",
issn      = "0927-0507",
doi       = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0927-0507(07)15011-8",
url       = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927050707150118",
}
```

(I obtained this information from the scidirect website.)